# Get The VMware Tools SVGA Driver On ReactOS?

Tags: drivers, vmware-player, vmware-tools, reactos

[image: ReactOS SVGA install screen]

I'm setting up a ReactOS 0.3.15 X86-32 virtual machine in VMware Player 6.0.1. VMware player doesn't officially support ReactOS so as suggested in the ReactOS installation guide (http://www.reactos.org/content/reactos-installation-guide#vmware) I'm using the "other" profile. ReactOS however has support (and automatically detects) the SVGA driver from VMware Tools for this whom wish to install it; I do. The problem is that there are no tools for the "other" profile, as depicted in my screenshot.

Which profile should I be using instead, better yet can I keep using the "other" profile, and just manually connect the appropriate tools iso? If so which iso do I need to use?

Comment: I've tried using Windows XP, and Windows 98 profiles but then the mouse doesn't work so I can't start the installation. I've tried, under the "other" profile to connect the windows and win2prek isos, but ReactOS can't find the driver on them.

Comment: Why do you need VMware Tools in ReactOS? It works perfect without it. For any needs it is beter to use Windows XP 32 bit profile.

Comment: I've already tried using the Windows XP profile, but I can't complete the installation process, because it causes issues with the mouse.

Comment: Why do you need VMware Tools in ReactOS?

Comment: @AlexanderRechitskiy I don't need them, but I'd like them. I always install tools in my VM's so I can get the most out of them.

Comment: Reactos works almost perfect without VMware Tools.

If you need it anyway, please visit our (ReactOS) bug-tracker or forum and post your feedback.

Please do not downvote my answers, because nobody else except me here is able to provide lot of information about ReactOS.

Comment: Questions about bugs in pre-release/beta software or prototype hardware are off-topic. Bugs in pre-release products are common and even expected, and are often fixed before the final version is released — at which point the question becomes obsolete. Consider reporting these types of problems directly to the product manufacturer.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I like how this question is only closed but the mods deleted all my questions on reactos

Comment: @EvanCarroll "Community" (the mod that deleted your questions) is not a real person. "Mods" did not delete your questions at all, they were cleaned up by automated tools created by Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReactOS may be a re-creation of the NT kernel in general, but in order to work with Windows software it has to
report itself as something recognizable. ReactOS is a server operating system so it currently reports itself as
Windows Server 2003. I'm not sure which exact version of Windows Server 2003 though.

Based on this it makes the most sense to use the the Windows Server 2003 Standard profile. If you get mouse issues, 
pull the bottom of the VMware screen up so you have a scrollbar, this should allow you to click the next button, and 
at the next screen the mouse should work correctly. Get rid of the scrollbar by re-pulling the screen bottom down, 
and proceed with the installation.

If you attempt to use the built in feature of ReactOS to install the SVGA driver from VMware Tools VMware will provide 
the correct iso, and if you're wondering it's "windows.iso". Unfortunately ReactOS still won't find the SVGA driver on 
the installation disc, because it's tucked away inside the vmware installer.

After you've finished installing ReactOS if you attempt to install the driver using the VMware Tools installer, it will
fail. Launch the VMware Tools installer, and choose "custom" setup type. Uncheck everything except the SVGA driver which 
should be set to "install entire feature". You will get an error from rundll32 saying "LoadLibrary failed to load 
'tpvmmon.dll'. The install process is just partially completed before the error. If you browse to the ReactOS Applications
 Manager you should see VMware Tools listed under "Installed", but if you look in your Device Manager you will see the 
display adapter is still using the driver provided by the ReactOS Team.

If you attempt to install the SVGA driver by manually the hard part is getting a hold of it, 
because it's buried away inside the VMware Tools installer. The simpliest way is to install VMware Tools on a 
Windows 98 virtual machine, and then browse to "C:\Programs\VMware\Vmware Tools\Drivers\video\vmx_svga.inf", and 
copy the SVGA driver. In ReactOS right click and choose to "install". This doesn't work either. After performing a
reboot you will still see the adapter is using the ReactOS Team's driver.

The fourth and final option is to take the copied driver and add it to the Vmware Tools "windows" iso file so that
when the ReactOS installer tries to find it, it isn't tucked away in the installer. This doesn't work either.

At this time it doesn't appear to be possible to install the SVGA driver, though it appears there are/were plans to make
it possible given that the ReactOS installation process includes the intended ability to do so.